# Is it sane to add cursor styles to table rows to indicate they are clickable

Tags: javascript, html-table, cursor, usability

This is rather a usability question, and would like some people who are in this field to answer this question. I got bunch of records displayed in table that have a Javascript click event added to each row so that more details can be viewed, edited. Like below

```
<tr onclick="location.href='?project.aspx?id=2'"> blah blah blah</tr>
```

In such a case should I display a cursor ( hand icon) denoting that the rows are clickable or should I educate my user using a message box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to have the hand icon if something is clickable. Since you have the entire row to be clickable, it is good to change the entire row color on hover too.. I hope this will give a good user experience to the users.

Comment: i will wait util i hear other opinions and arguments too thanks